# How to call a scope function based on an attribute value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have several 'save and close' links in my app, where each button has a unique function to run when clicked, defined by a directive `ng-really-click`. This directive confirms closing, then runs the close function, e.g.

```
<a ng-really-click="someCloseFunction(p1, p2)" />
```

Now from elsewhere in the app, I want to 'pretend' the user has clicked the save button, but bypass the confirmation. At any given moment, I don't know what close function should be called, and I have to find out which by finding the close link and inspecting its `ng-really-click` attribute.

Once I have the function call expression defined in the attribute, I would like to call that function against a scope I have in a variable `currentScope`. How can I do this?

Comment: That sounds like a really weird pattern that will create very high coupling in your app. Did you try to move the to-be-shared functionality into a service (which both your buttons, via their scopes, and your code elsewhere could use), then use angular's DI mechanisms to direct the execution towards that service?

Comment: @doldt That would be for a second iteration, where I have more freedom to make wider reaching changes,

Comment: So instead of just calling a function directly you want to examine a button to get the function and then invoke it? What's the point of that? How can the app know the button and at the same time be ignorant of the function? That makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

I gueess that the Angularish way would be to use different controllers per link. Then, have the scope and rootScope be pointers to an ng-really-click function. i.e:

Cntrl1:

```
$scope.funcPointer = $rootScope.funcPointer = function() {console.log('yo1');}
```

Cntrl2:

```
$scope.funcPointer = $rootScope.funcPointer = function() {console.log('yo2');}
```

On the views, use the func pointer:

```
<div ng-controller="Cntrl1"><a ng-really-click="funcPointer(p1, p2)" /></div>
```

And then from anywhere in the app, execute the function from the rootScope:

From any Ctrl:

```
$rootScope.funcPointer(val1, val2);
```

Comment: I'm trying to avoid knowing about all the ng-really-click functions at 'compile' time.

Comment: The 'someCloseFunction' called from the link must be defined under a scope, right? so you already "know" about it as you would in the suggested solution if I understand correctly. 

Do you mean you want to call the function outside an angular module? something like finding the scope from outside angular and invoking that function?

Comment: When my code that wants to 'click the button' runs, I don't know what scope is active, or which function the button will run, until I read that attribute.

Comment: If you do not know anything about which scope has the "current" function, the solution is to use the rootScope as I suggested. Not sure I get why you have to "read" the function from the attribute - in Angular, you cannot use the function in the attribute if you did not find it to the control's scope (so if you can get it from the attribute html, you can get it from the scope - and from the rootScope).

Comment: It's a matter of a dynamic function call. I have since solved it using `eval('currentScope' + functionExpression)` but was hoping to avoid `eval`. `currentScope` is a variable on `window` that always 'knows' what the current scope is.